# How can I use precompiled headers from a header file?

Tags: c++, include, precompiled-headers, cl, pch

distilled.cpp

```cpp
#include "distilled.hpp"

int main() {
    
}
```

distilled.hpp

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
```

batch

```
cl distilled.cpp /Yustdafx.h /Fpstdafx.pch /I include /std:c++20 /EHsc -DDEBUGMODE=true /c
```

This is the ideal setup but generates compiler errors.

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "distilled.hpp"

int main() {

}
```

This works fine. When the stdafx is included in the cpp file, it compiles blazing fast, which is very cool, but ideally, I would want to put that inclusion in another file. This approach also creates include errors in nested files(only in VSCode, not an actual compilation), where the compiler only works if I have `#include "stdafx.h"` exactly, but IntelliSense wants `#include "../stdafx.h"`. Am I doing something wrong to get this result?

Comment: Yes, but the solution to the include issue is to use `/Yu /Fpstdafx.pch` and then put `#pragma hdrstop("actualpath")` at the top of afflicted files

Comment: No, the solution is to not use precompiled headers in header files, as this is not the intended use.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I meant in reference to the include errors in every file inside a folder